# How to use a SVG file with animate taf in android Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, android, animation, svg, svg-animate

I am having an svg file containing animate tags, used for animation in webpages.

I tried importing the file into Android Studio, but the animate tag is not supported.

I tried looking for libraries, but all the libraries that i found only had functionality to draw the svg file using path data. My animation is not merely drawing the path. I want to animate exactly as it is in the webpage.

I read in some posts that AnimatedVectorDrawable can used, but it says in the documentation that it can be used to transform one shape into another. I dont want like that.

I have the svg file with the starting of the animation. If I can figure out the way to use this in android, my team is ready to prepare the whole animation in the same format.

I cant upload the full file, due to word limit, but i have deleted some part of the svg file and uploaded.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="750px"
     height="750px" viewBox="0 0 750 750" enable-background="new 0 0 750 750" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1">

        <image overflow="visible" width="102" height="157" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGYAAACdCAYAAAExjT0uAAAACXBIWXMAAA9hAAAPYQGoP6dpAAAK
T2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AU
kSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXX
Pues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh+PDwrIsAHvgAB
eNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAt
AGAnf+bTAICd+Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3
AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4AISZABRG8lc88SuuEOcqAAB4mbI8uSQ5RYFbCC1xB1dX
Lh4ozkkXKxQ2YQJhmkAuwnmZGTKBNA/g88wAAKCRFRHgg/P9eM4Ors7ONo62Dl8t6r8G/yJiYuP+
5p1ZC6I4sanu3RZHzGm4s1GywJ5P5z55Y4sRkqLHSDV4txTGG
gYJjwSXgRM1grhMVYvwtAx+fK7VS39GP+va+FU9ALjhFBCCtCDfmMl94wS9jNahM1EJ+rCsI3Y7E
iB8iaFSZNQCKE8RDDFzfPLUCVG/ZCVNoW1Ou8JyRvjG4Op349Y3tHT8OV/CsZ9EpGcORU7ApRgiN
gRQC4xpbTtfD+wkYmq0PDDgRg79/J4wlVz210rKLDGB/If8JBvNqUQSoRYo6ObYSlpBvGCnVvg5m
Z1a+LAgR9negdsMQKNQgw2tWUqYyGVPlutsT9uGEEN89OHp+4YnZnv4VBcYSRK5jWVoQQihRFyBd
1fxERZthQXSxtIQa9es2IbiqC1QPAcKaVl9TtZ+bYxJZZbA53faVnmSqspo0WWqOxywlSFiOrQnk
MyMQhEA3mG0JApIIpbD20ZB507SnxgxIAf81u6HT8SjfRWtTQqZUsxLANk8iowh1NiDI+tZ06kuB
DrCabFlKSWkrIZWUFII5BImQiMNoetDs+ZfRRWRgwDQR6Ox0YiDU4FwK1Zu3R26BXoOucOOEQnPE
ar/Nk4hLgm7024SGMZRKTMDa6/Yedvvzt++ubhI+Vr5CqDohlIKWCbp+CKqNh7avRD
q1tbNxoZy/nW9fnC+ydqYXHUr68ZlawY0agHNhyLObbT35FXOwc31Ayjkksn/fMTZb+3M4tzWRdH
qI7nq/U3V0MDV8lVubY0gHZF2OxJyIbR1nzhPInnlIxGQy8R/FBjMJn613cMDH2wWK8Gw5UKiACL
1g4ZlfrYnW90Rs6e1ZMVvzrQXage+O0RCIqSlDW/hmRvHmqgC71MIDLukxOTd660CptyebttgY2e
nK7uN1NGYj49NeM1gWHTEXP/9Kae7s+8qW8ARyYncH6NngmpQiZdGz51GqHW051RYajRXshgyzWb
EbMssGG4UuLA6Pl9h8vVDZYQKyItjQJIDMYEep1ocMX0gRW1/hl1rcO97Z3v35XN3vv0xDjqrFek
aG/JbIwxjFTMxdXXb0eYjuGM7wO+DyCay/LAyZP76gbClcsb25tGdmGzJ9FpCYTgCxF6i4AYwwjZ
HN7fseHDbx/Y+KNT1TJOVCbxYiGavEBeFBp0dbej1NeGI2ENVKxfFOlrY+Tj48XfFUTL9ueYAVsQ
tngSGQsND4tbFw1EjUWWkIdu6+x5c8B4tisWgyMl9IuM+1PpUKMrl8XuV+1CIICNTf6AKyQeHxsd
OuHXr1VLZCBnVnNqBhKSsDUuoqQiR6C0DAhFgKQt59EPDm2/I+3Yzx8aG8PRUhkv1qVGPIETKobh
sXNzvsgRAg+dPXe7r9m15VKBEnlTWSWw1RNQosEps5ALmyOXt+B6n+uLJ/7klbmOYEdbDs+WxvBi
X+o3xctTLzpC4Nmy/3ZcobRMmYewMYlqKCanZxabBYABRJOqtrdl/uHNfVd97GSljEMToy86dTUv
MJ2ON+8LJBGKQbDz+aq/VxFdkdoKGehzBQZdEXFTNmqWW0KDI9sWGlPt9ryP7Mpkv3RH30YcKZUQ
vgS5o1XamZ+RLiYlDk4Wf2+0HmKhs56nihsMRUnFHjtKmegFeFdAlCMNjSnf1tn9zo3J9P2/nRhF
3ZiXlITMAqY/kZp3YxURHh8/8m40mF64RXU15fJui0vkLIpOCBcCCEdRfcjmxGu7e997Z//Qjw9P
jmOkWsbLYanYPIXStpA4XJrY9tRkeaMtqSVANAOuBLZ7CokZx7YLsR8BG3hKPXJroev3S2F4MmnZ
CNjg5UR2rybN3G0WHhn8z7mz10+GOubMo8aokdFNScK2uGwkFaPE4kJUVmAMCrHYgx/YtP1dAjR6
tDSOsXodL8elJur+nBJQIohfjo6/a84EIUdHtHlbYEtsKqm4QBvCQM1o9HjxT/bEvI9fnS2gP5HE
s8VxvJyX0nO4RYoII5Vq13Olyg0zvbEpO6MZ6HEFrnIkQGZGUrEVMCLGy7rWuC7X/pev7e7/66Pl
qV9d1bTmDiM0ZrWEJgvO7fqWEgWaKmQxRc72s3
Fjo+8EK5Uk0qa93lXSlgOt3oBJOIELJJnPWrbzWaMdCW+pd3Dm7+8GQ9CI9VJqDXAVlZYDpcFwDg
SInfjJ27OWnbf7Uxlf7067v6kbQsjPq19V1ahbU+a3mNrvWRvmt0/f8AzPzlCkGC41sAAAAASUVO
RK5CYII=" transform="matrix(0.72 0 0 0.72 338 318)">

    </image>

    <animate id="Layer_1"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="0" to="1" dur="1s"
             begin="0s;animation2.end" />
    <animate id="Layer_1"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="1" to="0" dur="1s" 
             begin="animation1.end" />

</g>

<g id="Layer_2" opacity="0">

        <image overflow="visible" width="138"  height="184" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIoAAAC4CAYAAAFLMkRUAAAACXBIWXMAAA9hAAAPYQGoP6dpAAAK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" transform="matrix(0.72 0 0 0.72 288.3198 279)">

    </image>

    <animate id="Layer_2"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="0" to="1" dur="2s" 
             begin="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems You has `.png` images, not vectors inside your `SVG` file. So You can try split that `png` images to several separate `ImageView`s and apply animation for those `ImageView`s.

Comment: I received the same suggestion from my colleagues,  but I was hoping there was an easier way to do this... Isn't there any other way? isn't there any libraries that might help me achieve this? The process you mention will take time, since my animation is a bit large. So only before starting I am making sure there isn't a third party implementation to achieve my task...

Comment: Other way - convert bitmaps in `svg` to vectors, but it's more complex.

Comment: Can i use a Webview to directly use this svg? is that possible?

Comment: I think, unfortunately, no.